# Starting problem when it`s cold

Tags: starting, diesel, volvo, s40

I have an "S40" diesel VOLVO. Everything was fine about starting and things till I had to change the injection pump due to its leakage. Of course a brand new injection pump cost an arm and a leg, so I bought a second hand one which was much cheaper. Since then, I face problem with starting the engine and it takes a lot of effort to get it started in the end. I have to turn the ignition several times, consuming a lot of battery power so that it finally starts!

Is the problem because of the diesel? The injection pump? I cant make out what the main issue is here! Not to mention it started right away and so fast BEFORE I changed the injection pump!

Would someone advise me on this please? Thanks!

Comment: Usually, when a car was working before you did something, and now it's not, you have to look directly at what you were doing to see the answer. More than likely there is an issue with the injection pump. I wonder if it's sucking air somewhere? I would suggest the glow plugs, but since you said it was working fine before the pump, there's no reason to suspect them now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, everything was perfect before I changed the injection pump. It would start in a second, so fast no matter summer or winter, hot or cold!

Answer (score 2):

My first thing to look at is did you get the timing EXACTLY right? A small error can have a huge effect - one half a tooth can be the cause of excessive smoke - were the drive gears identical between the old and replacement : diameter, number of teeth?